# Cannot Retrieve Value From Last Insert Row in SQL Database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I've got a problem when retrieving the primary key value of the last inserted row in the database.

I have a table of name `wineDetails` which contains more than 2000 wine names. I display the names in alphabetical order.

When I add a new wine name into the `wineDetails` table, the new wine name primary key is 2001 in the database but when I am display the wine names in alphabetic order changes I get the primary key value of another wine name instead of 2001.

To get the last inserted rows primary kay I written the code as:

```
- (void)addWineDetails:(wineDetails *)awineDet 
{
    sqlite3_stmt *insert_statement;
    static char *sql = "INSERT INTO wineDetails (name,regionId,categoryId) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {       
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 1, [[awineDet wine_Name]UTF8String] , -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(insert_statement, 2,[awineDet region_Id]);
    sqlite3_bind_int(insert_statement, 3,[awineDet category_Id]);
    int success = sqlite3_step(insert_statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(insert_statement);
    if (success == SQLITE_ERROR)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to insert into the database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    } 
    else
    {
        primaryKey = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
        int lastInsertId =  sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
        wineDetPk = lastInsertId;
        printf("\n last insert id in adding:%d",lastInsertId);
        printf("\nwineDetPk id in adding:%d",wineDetPk);
    }
}
```

Guys please help me to get out of this.

Anyone's help wil be appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish Kumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Last Auto ID**
Is it generated by auto_increment?
If it is you can just use the insert function itself.

I also notice that you are trying to get the PK and the Insert ID. As far as I am aware the auto_increment **must** also be the primary key. So that it a little redundant.

If you add what the error is currently, I would be able to advice more.

Comment: Actually I am not getting any error.But I am not gettig the result what I expected.I need to get the last Inserted row's primary key after I changed the wine names into alphabetic order.but Im not getting the last Inserted pk value,I am getting the another primary key value which was replaced after changing into alphabetic order.